# Residence Permit in Greece (of Type D/National visa)

Tags: resident-permit, greece

I have a National/Type D visa issued by Greece for purpose indicated as "public interest" in the visa sticker (I am doing a clinical observership program in a public hospital). I arrived on October 20, and will be staying until April 26, 2020.

Am I required to apply for a residence permit, even if I am staying for less than a year? The consul herself in my home country was not sure of the answer. I read somewhere that residence permits are not required for stays more than 3 months but less than 1 year. Is this true?

Comment: What is the validity of your visa? For how many entries is it valid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are required to apply for a residence permit.

For most, but not all, countries the main purpose of the issuing of a D-Visa is for the issuing of a residence permit.

This defined in Article 7(1) LAW No 4251 for Greece, wheere no time contraint is meantioned.

See also the answer to

- [greece - Residence permit for Type D visa (for public interest) apply in Athens when I'm in Thessaloniki?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19405/17166)

---

**LAW No 4251** (Immigration and Social Integration Code and other provisions)

- **Article 7 Categories of residence permits**

> **1.** A third-country national who has been granted a visa in Greece for one of the reasons set out herein **must request a residence permit for the same reason on entry to the country**, without prejudice to the more specific Articles of this Code, provided that he meets the requirements set out in the Code.
>
> **2.** The categories of residence permits and the types of permissions that these include are:
> ...
> C3 Public interest
> ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Foreign Office National Visas - Visa Types](https://www.mfa.gr/en/visas/visa-types/national-visas.html)
- Pdf: [LAW No 4251 Immigration and Social Integration Code and other provisions](https://www.mfa.gr/images/docs/ethnikes_theoriseis/2015/metanast.pdf)

  - from 2014-04-01