# Residence permit for Type D visa (for public interest) apply in Athens when I'm in Thessaloniki?

Tags: resident-permit, greece

I have a type D visa (category is "gamma 2: public interest") valid from October 18 2019 - May 1 2020 (less than 1 year). I am currently in Thessaloniki for a clinical observership/shadowing in a hospital.

Today I went to the Immigration Office to ask if I am required to get a residence permit, and their answer to me was to go to an office in Athens at Evaggelistrias 2 and apply there. The lady also told me to send an email to legislation@immigration.gov.gr to confirm that it is in Athens I have to apply.

Has anyone had any similar experience? My understanding is that residence permits are to be applied to in the city where the third national is residing. Did I go to the wrong office or the wrong department?

Answer (score 0):

Article 8(2) of **LAW No 4251** states that the application of the residence permit can be done either **localy** or at the National **Directorate for Immigration Policy to the Ministry for the Interior**

Based on your information, you are being asked by the *local Immigration Office* to **send an email** to *legislation@immigration.gov.gr* to ask them **where you should actually go** to get this done.

As to the reason **why** they are asking you do this, is not clear.

The best thing to do (for lack of further information) is to send the email as requested, stating also the date and time and from where you exactly asked (address).

This would seem to be a

- [**Ours not to reason why, ours but to do and die**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Charge_of_the_Light_Brigade_(poem))

situation.

---

**LAW No 4251** (Immigration and Social Integration Code and other provisions)

- **Article 7 Categories of residence permits**

> **1.** A third-country national who has been granted a visa in Greece for one of the reasons set out herein **must request a residence permit for the same reason on entry to the country**, without prejudice to the more specific Articles of this Code, provided that he meets the requirements set out in the Code.
>
> **2.** The categories of residence permits and the types of permissions that these include are:
> ...
> C3 Public interest
> ...

- **Article 8 Granting of Residence Permit**

> **2.** Applications for residence permits shall be lodged with the **one-stop agency of the competent directorate for aliens and immigration of the decentralised administration in the applicant’s area of residence**, or **with the competent Directorate for Immigration Policy to the Ministry for the Interior**, pursuant to the provisions of Article 2 of Law 4018/2011 (Government Gazette, Series A, No 215). Submission of an application for initial residence permit, submission of additional supporting documents and collection of the residence permit or the rejection decision, or other documents from the relevant file, may be made by a third-country national in person or he may be represented by an authorised attorney, or his spouse, ascendants and adult descendants. Authorisation shall be proven in writing by having the authenticity of the authorising person’s signature attested by any public authority. Service by bailiff of any document or supporting documents for the issue or renewal of a residence permit shall not be allowed.

---

**Sources**:

- [Foreign Office National Visas - Visa Types](https://www.mfa.gr/en/visas/visa-types/national-visas.html)
- Pdf: [LAW No 4251 Immigration and Social Integration Code and other provisions](https://www.mfa.gr/images/docs/ethnikes_theoriseis/2015/metanast.pdf)

  - from 2014-04-01